# Apache Karaf - Unable to resolve root: missing requirement - caused by: Unable to resolve java-api

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf

I have Apache Karaf 4.0.1 running on a Linux Centos 7 server.

I get the following error:

```
org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=travellinck-osgi; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.4,1.0.4]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=travellinck-osgi)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.0.4)(version<=1.0.4))" [caused by: Unable to resolve travellinck-osgi/1.0.4: missing requirement [travellinck-osgi/1.0.4] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=com.travellinck.transIT.java-api; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.153.0,1.153.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve com.travellinck.transIT.java-api/1.153.0: missing requirement [com.travellinck.transIT.java-api/1.153.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.jws)(version>=1.1.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"]]
    at org.apache.felix.resolver.Candidates.populateResource(Candidates.java:314)[org.apache.felix.framework-5.0.1.jar:]
```

Any ideas?

I am a novice with apache-karaf/OSGi, so please excuse me if there is pertinent information lacking in this question, I would be glad to add info when suggested.

**More info:**

I build it using maven with Java1.7. I also tried building it with Java8, but there is no change.

In reference to this part of the error message:

```
caused by: Unable to resolve com.travellinck.transIT.java-api/1.153.0
```

In one of the modules, there is the following in the POM:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.travellinck.integration.vocabulary</groupId>
<artifactId>com.travellinck.transIT.java-api</artifactId>
<version>1.153.0</version>
<name>${bundle.name} ${project.version} [osgi]</name>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<description>Comprehensive travel services vocabulary</description>
```

Comment: The error says that there is no bundle providing javax.jws inside the OSGi environment, can you do a classes | grep -i javax.jws ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by removing these dependencies from the pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the end of your error, it says : "Hey, I miss this package : javax.jws, and I want it with version >= 1.1 but not superior of 2.0.0"

You fixed that problem by removing all those  dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.7</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Why does it need it ? Because the maven-bundle-plugin that you surely use, scan the dependencies and creates Import-Package clauses in the MANIFEST.MF which list all the packages needed to run your bundle.

If you didn't needed them, good ! But if in the end you needed them, it's not a problem ! You just have to ensure that the package javax.jws is installed with the version 1.1.

I suppose this package is exported by javax.jws-api, which has a similar name and is also at version 1.1. So, in your karaf, you can do `bundle:install mvn:javax.jws/javax.jws-api/1.1` and in theory, your bundle will found the required packages now

To be sure, you can download the jar from maven central repo and check in it the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, which contains :

```
Export-Package: javax.jws;version="1.1.0",javax.jws.soap;version="1.1.0"
```

This means "I'm the exporter of javax.jws package at version 1.1.0". If you install it, your other bundle will be able to find that package.